# Bash shell command inline correction

Tags: bash, shell

When typing a (long) command in the bash shell, if you were to make a mistake early in the line, is there a way to correct that mistake without having to navigate back to it? For example, lets say you have just entered something like this, but not yet pressed return:

```
git commit =m 'Some really long commit message, perhaps spanning multiple lines'
```

where you have accidentally typed **=** instead of **-**, would it be possible to append something to the end of the command before you press enter that would perform an in-line substitution to correct the mistake? This would be really handy to avoid having to do something annoying like

- Pressing `Ctrl+C` and then rebuilding the command using a combination of copy and paste.
- Pressing the left arrow a huge bunch of times so that it can be corrected before pressing enter.

One solution (in theory) would be to pipe the contents of the whole command through `sed`, however I am not sure how to capture the command as a string of text that could then be used in this manner.

Comment: I'd press `C-a` (return to the beginning of the line). And then `C-e` (end of line) if I wasn't finished there

Comment: It's rebindable, `C-a` is from emacs.

Comment: Of course it's rebindable, but `C-a` is usually the default on e.g. Bash (emacs mode)

Comment: Btw, **if** you have already pressed enter, type `^=^-` to replace first `=` by `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do : <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

then move the cursor after the `=`, then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>.

The latest delete the previous word.

Comment: I'd use backspace. I guess the vim gods will strike me down now

Comment: ctrl+w was just to add another trick. Sure backspace will do it too ;)

Comment: That works great (and shame on me for not searching the web for 'bash shell go to start of line'). There are of course some cases where this won't work (if keys are rebound, and it didn't work for me inside a screen session) but in general this looks to be the right approach.

Comment: I didn't realise my approach was (somewhat) universal. I assumed someone would answer with some cool sed :p This is pragmatic though.

Comment: Also Meta-f (normally Escape *followed by* "f", not keyed simultaneously) will move forward whole words, just as Meta-b will move backwards whole words. So ctrl-a esc-f esc-f will get you to the space before the '='. And if you really want to go nuts, ctrl-x ctrl-e will open the command line in your editor of choice (`$VISUAL`).

Comment: `CTRL + h` deletes last character.  Perfect for when your `Backspace` key is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple shortcuts can help here:

- Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line
- Use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to move forward and backward one word at a time
- Use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to **open an editor** ($EDITOR) containing your current command, edit it, then close your editor.